# Interface class to implement

Tags: c++

I'm coming from PHP and I'm expecting to get an error message if I don't implement a method in a class that's based on an interface.

```
class Screen {
    public:
        virtual void drawScreen();  // Needs to be implemented by each subclass 
};
class LanguageScreen : public Screen {
    // I didn't define the void drawScreen();
};
```

So I actually want to get a message that the method `drawScreen()` is missing in the class `LanguageScreen` since it implements the "interface" class `Screen`. Or is this different to PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a *pure virtual* function.

The difference:

- Virtual: I will implement it, but you can override it
- Pure virtual: I will define it, but you *must* implement it

To make a virtual function pure virtual you just assign it the value 0:

```
class Screen {
    public:
        virtual void drawScreen() = 0;  // Needs to be implemented by each subclass 
};
class LanguageScreen : public Screen {
    // I didn't define the void drawScreen();
};
```

Which results in this when you try and use it (by "use" I mean try and instantiate an object directly from the subclass):

```
error: cannot declare variable 'foo' to be of abstract type 'LanguageScreen'                  
note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'LanguageScreen':            
note:        'virtual void Screen::drawScreen()'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206393/discussion-on-answer-by-majenko-interface-class-to-implement).